# access data frame by mapping through a lookup table

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame a and a lookup table where I want to add tags to the data.frame a based by mapping from the lookup table. The mapping does not work correctly.

The correct result should be:   4, 2, 4, 4 
while I get:   2 3 2 2

```
a = data.frame (id = c("c", "b", "c", "c"), val = c(1,2,3,4))
lookup = data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), val = c(3,2,4,5))
print(lookup[a$id, "val"])
```

I also tried this:

```
a = data.frame (id = c("c", "b", "c", "c"), val = c(1,2,3,4))
lookup = data.frame(row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), val = c(3,2,4,5))
print(lookup[a$id, "val"])
```

still wrong result.

Comment: What's the expected result? Did you try `match`?

Comment: I doubt it is a version specific problem. Can you produce any specific examples for verification?

Comment: You really haven't shown this to be a problem and I am voting to close (I would reverse if you demonstrate there is a problem).  First define best.  Secondly what versions of R does this not work for?  Right now this is opinion based and as far as a lookup question this has been asked numerous times before on SO.

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised that I got any result:

```
X = data.frame(id = c("c", "b", "a", "b", "a", "a", "c"), val = c(33,22,45,66,11,77,99))
lookup = data.frame( id = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), val = c(11,22,33,44))
lookup[X$id, "val"]
[1] 33 22 11 22 11 11 33
```

But:

```
> lookup[c("c", "b", "a", "b", "a", "a", "c"), "val"]
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Your conceptual problem is that you think and R has somehow conspired to allow you to continue in the misconception, that the first column should be used as an indexing. R dataframes have rownames which can be used for index lookups but the default for rownames are character vectors formed for 1:nrow(dfrm), not the first column, even if it has the name "id" or "ID". This alternate strategy should succeed:

```
lookup = data.frame( row.names = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), val = c(11,22,33,44))

lookup[X$id, "val"]
#[1] 33 22 11 22 11 11 33
lookup[c("c", "b", "a", "b", "a", "a", "c"), "val"]
#[1] 33 22 11 22 11 11 33
```

I didn't know at first why the call `lookup[X$id, "val"]` succeeded. I didn't think it should have done so. Oh, never mind, it was a factor and not a character value. I'm tripped up by factors yet again. The numeric representation of X$id was being used as the lookup so any success was entirely accidental.

What should be done? (Now using the edited examples above) Let's assume you made your second example. Either use a named vector or use `match`. And wrap as.character around factors when using them for character lookups. Here are examples of each:

```
> val <- setNames( c(3,2,4,5),c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
> val[ as.character(a$id)]
c b c c 
4 2 4 4 

> lookup[ as.character(a$id), 'val']
[1] 4 2 4 4
```

And if using the first example:

```
> a = data.frame (id = c("c", "b", "c", "c"), val = c(1,2,3,4))
> lookup = data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), val = c(3,2,4,5))
> lookup[match(a$id, lookup$id), "val"]
[1] 4 2 4 4
```

Comment: What is the correct way of accessing a dataframe based on a mapping from a look up table which is mentioned above? We could use merge or match but once the dataframe is very large (>100000 rows) it takes a long time to work. I think there should be an easy way of indexing based on another lookup table.

Comment: `match` is very fast if used properly.

Comment: The reason you are getting NA is because your first entry should be in factor. So use as.factor(c("c", "b"))

Comment: That will give extremely unstable results. Try it. The results will be different for `as.factor(c('c','b')`. You don't get error reports but the results will be erroneous.

Comment: If you are very careful you can get this method to work, but why persist in using a method that will be unstable and misleading in the long run?

Comment: I changed the id to row.names for above problem which I have changed some minutes ago by the way. But the result is still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the `lookup` or `%l%` function in the qdap package.

```
> library(qdap)

> a = data.frame (id = c("c", "b", "c", "c"), val = c(1,2,3,4))
> lookUp = data.frame(id = c("a", "b", "c", "d"), val = c(3,2,4,5))

> a$id %l% lookup
[1] 4 2 4 4
```